# Unable to perform ´tmux ls´

Tags: tmux, byobu

Im currently experiencing this issue with byobu (using tmux as backend) where basically I cannot attach to any tmux/byobu session. More simply, I cannot even list them. If I try to do a `tmux ls`,  what i get is a `failed to connect to server`

```
[1] $ byobu -v
byobu version 5.92
tmux 1.8
```

That's rather bizzare, since I can see many processes running:

```
ps aux | grep tmux | cut -f 1 -d ' ' --complement
  10207  0.0  0.0  22576  2092 ?        Ss   17:47   0:01 tmux -2 -f /usr/share/byobu/profiles/tmuxrc new-session -n - /usr/bin/byobu-shell
  13569  0.0  0.0  22588  2148 ?        Ss   17:49   0:00 tmux -2 -f /usr/share/byobu/profiles/tmuxrc new-session -n - /usr/bin/byobu-shell
 40025  0.0  0.0 113264  1708 pts/12   Ss+  Apr27   0:00 bash -c tmux a -t base || tmux new -s base
 40091  0.0  0.0  20000  1100 pts/12   S+   Apr27   0:00 tmux new -s base
 40093  0.1  0.0  30484  9984 ?        Ss   Apr27   6:02 tmux new -s base
 58042  0.0  0.0  22592  2152 ?        Ss   18:55   0:00 tmux -2 -f /usr/share/byobu/profiles/tmuxrc new-session -n - /usr/bin/byobu-shell
 58191  0.0  0.0  19996  1092 pts/1    S+   18:55   0:00 tmux -2 -f /usr/share/byobu/profiles/tmuxrc new-session -n - /usr/bin/byobu-shell
  58226  0.5  0.0  22580  2092 ?        Ss   18:55   0:02 tmux -2 -f /usr/share/byobu/profiles/tmuxrc new-session -n - /usr/bin/byobu-shell
  63085  0.0  0.0 112664   980 pts/11   S+   19:01   0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn tmux
 64900  0.0  0.0 545276 524808 ?       Ss   Apr27   1:44 tmux
```

I've already tried the trick of sending `USR1` signal, but it did not work. 
Each time I call byobu I attach to a new session, and there´s not way to attach.. 
I tried to reconfigure the package with `yum reinstall byobu` but nothing changed. 
Byobu-screen instead works as expected, so I think is a tmux issue.

Comment: Did you perhaps upgrade tmux while sessions were running?

Comment: Good guess, but no. It´s problem even for newly created sessions :(